# Where is logs for Spring Cloud Data Flow Stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am using Spring Cloud Data Flow Stream. I have launched 3 spring boot apps as a stream. namely source, processor & sink.

How can i see the logs of these spring boot apps? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can look at http://localhost:9393/runtime/apps to see stdout in attributes to see where the logs are